Should I mention a 5 month grad program on my CV?
I was made redundant from a graduate program earlier this year in July, based in Australia which lasted 5 months and 1 week.
TL; DR: There wasn't enough billable work available for me. I've left with some references though.
Longer Answer: When I joined the company, the manager who hired me was in talks of moving to Seattle, which left my team in a state of uncertainty with rumours of dissolution. During the first three months, I was frequently told I would be changing teams and managers and then that I wouldn't be. My manager, concerned for her job, often aired me. Things improved once I got a new, supportive manager, but shortly thereafter, I was let go due to not billing enough work and possibly due to a senior staff member's dislike of me. A few other graduates were also let go though none as new as me.
I’m finding it more challenging to secure a graduate job now compared to before and wonder if the short tenure in the previous program is negatively impacting my applications. Do you think I should omit this experience and state I took a gap year instead?
To add, I have recently secured a new graduate program a couple days ago, although to put it bluntly it’s not my end goal. Should I leave out my previous negative experience on my CV?
Thanks for your insights.

What does "made redundant from a graduate program" mean in this context? Were you working for a university, or were you in a degree program? I also don't understand exactly what you mean by "secured a new graduate program".

In the U.S. at least, the title means that you were attending university for post-college education, and in that context it doesn't make sense to say that you were "made redundant." Can you rephrase this question to clarify what you mean by this?

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine in British English anyway (and I think Australian English), a graduate program can also be a scheme run by an employer where they employ new graduates, typically given them exposure to a number of departments in a relatively short timespan. Further education after your first degree would typically be called a "postgraduate course".

@PhilipKendall So it's like a rotational development program in the U.S.?

No so my understanding of a grad program is that it’s a job for graduates (typically undergrad or higher) that has more structure, is usually for a larger company, and typically include rotations which a ‘grad job’ likely doesn’t encompass. I suppose all grad programs are grad jobs but not the other way round. Take a look at the differences on google. I’ll link an info page from the uni I went to but I didn’t really think about the differences between America and Australia. https://www.eait.uq.edu.au/employability/blog/2021/01/graduate-program-graduate-job-whats-the-difference

Never lie. Let me say that louder for the people at the back.
NEVER LIE
There are few things will can erode trust in someone quicker than finding out they've lied to you - and these sort of things have a way of coming out. Employers understand the economy isn't the greatest right now and people are let go for reasons beyond their control, particularly junior staff. You're almost certainly reading too much into your more difficult job hunt.

Agreed. As a hiring manager, and as someone who has been made redundant twice, this situation is not something that would concern me. Lying on the other hand is an immediate disqualifier.

Yeah, Layoffs happen. If it is a pattern? Then it might be hard to get a job... But one or 2 isntances in a row? Not a red flag.

Thanks for your input and seems like others are in agreement. Was just something I was very unsure about how others might perceive it.

@CuriousBean - Only you can answer if the experience you gain while employed was a net benefit, being let ago after 5 month from non-permanent position, doesn’t seem to be a factor in the decision making especially with anyone familiar running similar graduate programs since they understand their non-permanent funding dependent nature. If the program was in your field, and you gained experience, showing any expertise over someone without any seems to be a positive thing to show. Since you don’t know the reason you were let ago, focus on the most likely cause, lack of funding (billable hours)
